# bootstrap-datetimepicker got cut in half on mobile version

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

hello guys i want to ask you how to make the dropdown of date time picker smaller. because it got cut when mobile version @media (max-width: 435px). i dont know what class that i have to edit. because when i try to inspect the dropdown it just close and i cant find the div.
all i got class when inspect just like this

```
<div class="bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget dropdown-menu usetwentyfour top pull-right>
```

but i dont know what element they got inside that div

[heres the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKdwf.png)

[heres with inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMG2k.png)

Answer (score 0):

you try to live your project or you set position on phone by media queries
without  live it very hard. you try different  data picker by http://bootsnipp.com/